# Refresh react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My node.js server sends with socket.io new data each 10s. In my web application I update this.state each time that my server sends data and force to update with forceUpdate()

However, my react component doesn't refresh, I don't know why. I followed the doc but I missed something...

**Parent :**

```
class DataAnalytics extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    socket = this.props.socket;
    this.state = {data: []};

    socket.on('dataCharts', (res) => {
      console.log("new data charts : "+res);
      var data = JSON.parse(res);   
      this.setState({data: data});
      this.forceUpdate();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    socket.off('dataCharts');
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div id="dataAnalytics">
      <Stats data={this.state.data}></Stats>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataAnalytics;
```

**Child :**

```
class Stats extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="stats" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
        <h4>Number: </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    var data = this.props.data;

    if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
      $( ".stats" ).html("<h4>Number : data['nb']['counterIn']</h4>");
    }
  }
}

export default Stats;
```

Anyone know how to refresh automatically my React component.

Comment: `this.setState()` might help you

Comment: I have this.setState() in my parent component... I tried to place it in different method (componentDidUpdate, componentWillMount ...), but same result :/

Comment: Your setup inside parent looks correct: data should be new on every cycle, and setState() should re-render parent +child, without even need for forceUpdate(). Are you sure the socket works properly? Do you get multiple console.log lines?

Answer (score 4):

The React component doesn't update because it doesn't realize that it's state changes. You can force an update on a React component by creating it each time with a different `key` attribute.

```
render() {
     return (
         <div id="dataAnalytics">
             <Stats key={this.uniqueId()} data={this.state.data}></Stats>
         </div>
    );
}

// Example of a function that generates a unique ID each time
uniqueId: function () {
    return new Date().getTime();
}
```

Comment: that isn't  correct answer, you can trigger `setState` event if you dont change your state [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/356/) and it will re-render compoenent

Comment: @The: you are correct. But I'm thinking that he wants it to respond when data changes, without having to manually trigger setState. I was expecting React to work like that also, but I was having sub-components that didn't update because their state was not really updating. So I'm using on some of my components this "trick" with the key attribute

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But I need more precision. How to use correctly this uniqueId on my child component ? For the moment with this unique id my method componentDidUpdate() is not called :/ so any informations are displayed.

Comment: @RaulRene i see, i havent faced with something similar

Comment: The trick with unique IDs in keys is only relevant if you have a list of children, and some children do not rerender properly. (I would advise a more proper and efficient key though). OP's issue is unrelated to lists, so I doubt key/ID will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like -

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [_, refresh] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Code that's supposed to run on refresh
  }, [refresh])

  return 
    <>
      {/* Rest of the code */}
      <button onclick={() => refresh(true)}>Refresh</button>
    </>

}
```

The idea is to define a state and use it as a dependency of `useEffect`s (or `useMemo`s and `useCallback`s).

If there are multiple effect hooks, add `refresh` to all of them as a dependency.